# Copying and comparing individual element from 2D array to another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

```
char first_array[5][4] = {"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"};
char second_array[1][4];
```

How would I copy, for example, the third element in first_array ("ccc") and save it to second_array?

The syntax below is clearly wrong, but this is what I'm asking for:

```
second_array[0] = first_array[2];
```

Also, after copying, I also want to know how to compare elements in the two arrays. Again, the syntax below might be wrong, I'm just explaining what I'm trying to do:

```
if(second_array[0] == first_array[2]){ printf("yes"); } //should print yes
```

Comment: `strncpy(second_array[0], first_array[2], 4);` or perhaps `memcpy()`?

Comment: Perfect, strncpy works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to arrays in c, you can fill arrays with some library functions like `strcpy()`, so

```
second_array[0] = first_array[2];
```

would be

```
strcpy(second_array[0], first_array[2]);
```

you must however ensure that the destination array fits the number of characters you are copying to it.

If you try to compare two strings in c, you can't do it through the `==` operator, because strings in c are arrays of `char` which contain a sequence of non-`nul` characters followed by a `nul` character, so if you write this

```
if (second_array[0] == first_array[2])
```

even when you succeeded at copying the data, the result will be most likely false, because you are not comparing the contents of the arrays, but their addresses, so to compare them correctly there is also a function `strcmp()` then the correct way of comparing the strings is

```
if (strcmp(second_array[0], first_array[2]) == 0)
```

The functions above require you to include the `string.h` header, and also that the passed strings are strings in the c sense, i.e what I described above.

Comment: Great! strncpy and strcmp is exactly what I need

Comment: @0100100001101001 be careful with `strncpy` as it does not generate a null-terminated string in some cases. Instead check the buffer sizes and use `strcpy`/`memcpy`;  or use `snprintf`.

Answer (score -1):

I was recently trying to do this, as well: **it is not possible to do this sort of direct assignment in C**.

When you write `first_array[0]`, the compiler will read that as an address which points to the first element (character) of `first_array[2]`, not the entire string. When you run the assignment, if it were to work, it would only set the first character.

The easiest way is to use `strncpy` or `memcpy` (or a loop to cycle through the string.

Comment: Did you ask this on SO?

Comment: Why would a loop be necessary?

Comment: We have a 2D array; this direct assignment isn't possible. A loop is necessary if you use strong copy.

Comment: @baum - Not sure what you mean by **strong copy**, however a loop is **not** required since you only need to use `strcpy` or `strncpy` to get the desired result.

Comment: Curious, why **Unfortunately**?

Comment: Meant "string". Autocorrect took over. And a loop seems messy. Memcpy (or equivalent for strings) is much nicer.